# react-native-tab-view crashes in release mode, but works fine in debug mode

Tags: react-native-tab-view

I'm using TabView component from react-native-tab-view. It works great in the debug mode but in the release mode, it crashes.

I'm using
"react-native-tab-view": "2.16.0",
"react-native": "0.72.3",

I saw it is an issue in ios.
https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view/issues/1277